# rebuild a code from a decompiled java code

Tags: java

how to rebuild a code from a decompiled java code and how to modify the classes whose name contains $ to suit the application

Comment: You should always get the original source - even the best decompiler cannot guarantee a correct result, and there is no comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) is better choice for decompiling than jad. JAD is not updated for many years.

Answer (score 2):

Use a decompiler like JAD.  The generated clases like $1 are anonymous classes which JAD should decode for you.